# Do I have to use geojson files to get data when I click polygons on the map in mapbox gl js?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I have 16,000 rows of data in excel.
In this excel, I have [census block numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Census_block).
What I want to achieve is that I want to make a map layer for these block numbers.
Then, if I click a polygon, the information of a block number display on the popups, like which state, county, and so on.

How can I do that? Do I have to use geojson files for this?
Because, many exmaples in the mapbox use geojson.
But I don't have any coordinates for these block numbers and 16,000 rows are really big to me. I got only block numbers.

But I got shapefiles for whole state block numbers.It is too big to upload mapbox gl js.

If geojson file is the way to achieve my goal, can someone tell me the orders that I can follow?
Or is there other way, please advise me.
Thanks.

Comment: https://blog.mapbox.com/the-net-neutrality-map-how-i-built-it-c387c9cb64a8

Answer (score 0):

So you have a geometry file ("shapefiles for whole state block numbers") and a data file ("16,000 rows of data in excel"). You want the user to click on a boundary in the geometry, and see data from the data file. You have two main options:

- Join the data and geometry first (eg, use [geojson-join](https://github.com/node-geojson/geojson-join), then upload to Mapbox as a tileset.
- Upload just the geometry. Load the CSV file when the web page loads, then when the user clicks, display something from the CSV file.